# WiFi lost error

Tags: firebase, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I use Firebase on NodeMCU. When using the `firebase.get` ~ function, there is no problem with the WiFi connection. but, I get an error if the Wi-Fi connection is lost. I try to reconnect the Wi-Fi after catching this error. However, there is no way to determine this error.

> Error in serial window:
>   Exception (28):
>   epc1 = 0x402038c0 epc2 = 0x00000000 epc3 = 0x00000000 excvaddr = 0x03350089 depc = 0x00000000
>
> Error with esp exception decoder:
>   Exception 28: LoadProhibited: A load referenced a page mapped with an attribute  that does not permit loads
>   Decoding 56 results

Action plan (if WiFi signal is disconnected)

1.

```cpp
boolean check = Firebase.getBool (path);

if (Firebase.error ()) {
    Serial.println ("error ()");
}

if (Firebase.failed ()) {
    Serial.println ("failed ()");
}

if (Firebase.success ()) {
    Serial.println ("success ()");
}
```

Failure to catch error

2.

```cpp
if (WiFi.isConnected ()) {
    Serial.println ("WiFi.isConnected ()");
    boolean check = Firebase.getBool (path);
}

if (WiFi.status ()! = WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println ("WL_CONNECTED");
}

if (WiFi.status () == WL_DISCONNECTED) {
    Serial.println ("WL_DISCONNECTED");
}
```

`Firebase.get` ~ error occurs before `WiFi.status ()` is slow and status changes.